# airodump-ng not shows stations in 16.04LTS

Tags: aircrack-ng

After i made a clean install 16.04LTS from  14.04LTS the airmon-ng not working as expected.It is not showing any associated stations anymore.I am using Ralink RT2870/3070  rt2800usb - [phy0] driver.It was working before in 14.04LTS.Are the drivers properly patched in 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

The current solution is buy a new wireless card.Because currently there is no solution to get airmon-ng worked properly with  Ralink RT2870/3070 rt2800usb drivers in Ubuntu 16.04LTS.As a reference my new driver is  **rtl8192cu** and working as expected.